# Node.js unit testing problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, web-applications

I have a web app that I have to perform unit tests on. I'm really new to testing so am having some problems. I am using mocha and chai and have been able to set up a simple test to pass that simply checks a function to return a string, but am struggling to apply tests to my more complicated functions.

The code I am trying to create tests for is to test a function that removes users items from a shopping cart I have created.

```
 this.removeItem = function(id) {
        this.totalQty -= this.items[id].qty;
        this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].price;
        delete this.items[id];

    };
```

Comment: What have you tried? What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This code should be pretty straightforward to exercise:

- instantiate your object

  `var obj = new YourObj();`
- add some sort of `items`
- call remove item with the id of the item you added
- assert that `obj.items` is back to empty